# trouble with adding a logo on a material

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I have issues to put a logo on a surface that already has a material and it make a pink color that blend with the transparency but on the right on the preview we can see the résulte that i want. It's only for one face of the 6 so i duplicate the material for one face and and the image on the new material, add the image on the uv editor and unwarp the face.

Comment: imho strange material setup... which UV should be used by texture coordinate node? and why non-color data for the image texture? is it a normal map? I can't understand what you wish to obtain, and which image are you using...

Comment: oh sorry the non-color data and the coordinate were a test i just forgot to undo that.

Comment: and i just begin with nods so if the material is strange you can say what's seems wrong

Comment: Argh, I was _just_ about to post an answer! (:

Comment: And @Baptiste, your setup looks good to me, except I would plug the Alpha into the Fac of the last Mix node.

Comment: I tried and the preview looks better but it's steel look pink in the render. I don't understand what's wrong cause the preview is exactly what I want in my render. And my image is just a logo with no background.

Comment: @seaturtle please post an answer

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped it yet?

Comment: yes I already UV unrapped it and put it like i want and the image

Comment: Probably you have some problem with your environment map not found or something like that that causes the material to reflect pink...

Comment: I try on a other surface and it's the same result so it something i do wrong but i don't no what

Comment: Is the type of image changes things like if png don't work ?

Comment: i change in the image texture node the extantion to clip and now i can see taht the pink is the rectangle of the image in the uv editor.